# What would this curl-request look like in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, curl

How would I do the following request in Node.js?

`curl "https://mysite.com/page " -F 'format=js' -F 'attachment[a]=1' -F'attachment[attachment]=@file.txt'`

I've tried using [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler), but I'm doing something wrong. Not sure what.

```
var restler = require('restler');
var fs = require('fs');

var email = 'me@me.com',
    password = 'mypass',
    url = 'https://mysite.com/something';

fs.stat('test.txt', function(err, stats) {
  restler.postJson(url, JSON.stringify({
    format: 'js',
    attachment: restler.file('test.txt', null, stats.size,
                             null, 'text/plain')
  })).on('complete', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use node-curl, I think is better for your scope and [documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-curl) is clear.

```
curl(url, [options = {}], callback)
callback includes 1 parameters (error)
result is stored in curl
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!